# Capital letter after adverb

Tags: adverbs, sentence, capitalization

In sentences like:

> - Also, it provides ...
> - Also, It provides ...

is it allowed to place *It* (with a capital *I*) instead of *it* after the adverb *Also*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**.

And it has nothing to do with using an adverb. It also has nothing to do with using the word "also". Simply, if the word is not at the *very* beginning of the sentence (and is not a proper noun), it should not be capitalized. Since "it" is neither the first word in your sentence, nor a proper noun, "it" should be lowercase.

Comment: *I* counts as a proper noun.

Comment: I suppose *I* is a proper pronoun. Here's some background on it: http://blog.dictionary.com/whycapitali/ . I didn't include *all* capitalization rules because I was trying to keep the answer simple for the questioner. Given her question, sticking to absolute basics seemed appropriate.

Comment: Also, I will try to ....

Comment: +1@Raj, I gave an example...did not challenge the answer.

Comment: ‘If we accept the axiom that trivial questions are bad for the site, then the proper response to a general reference question is: 1.Don't answer! 2… [Vote] to close. The point is not to encourage trivial questions. If you post an answer or vote up an existing answer, you're implicitly encouraging more questions like it.’ –Martha

Comment: Trivial to whom? It's not trivial to the OP. Most questions can be answered by Googling and landing at a different site. You're saying you only want the hardest questions here, for which an answer cannot be found elsewhere? That would preclude half the Q/A's on SE.